# vb script to delete all sent items

Tags: vbscript, outlook

I need to run a script that clear the outlook sent items after another script that send 10,000 emails automatically so the sent mail box got oversize error(the delete after send rule didnt work when you use a script to send emails...).
Any ideas ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why not set the MailItem.DeleteAferSubmit property to true if you are sending the messages programmatically?

Comment: i did it, but it dosen't work when you send your emails with a script, it's really weird ...